# setting up virtualenvwrapper on windows

Tags: windows, cmd, environment-variables, virtualenvwrapper

I'm using virtualenv wrapper on my mac, and I like it a lot. I'm trying to get the equivalent program to work on my windows box.

The main question I have is how to do the equivalent of
export WORKON_HOME=[BLAH BLAH]

I have some already existing venvs on a shared drive that I'd like to be able to use with this... How do I set this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwindows%5D+set+environment+variable

Comment: Reinstated virtualenvwrapper tag because I'm not actually sure what the variable name is or if it even exists because it's not in the documentation.... (and it's a port, so some things may be different)

Answer (score 0):

to save future seekers the extra clicks:

in normal windows command line,

```
setx WORKON_HOME [path to venvs]
```

works (but only for NEW commandlines)

Comment: `set WORKON_HOME=[path to venvs]` works in the current command line.